# TypeGuard function for a key in a generic object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to create a TypeScript type guard function that determines if a given key is in a given (generic) object — very similar to `key in obj`, but as a functional type guard (required for reasons unrelated to this question).

For example, something like this:

```js
export function has<T extends { [index: string]: any; [index: number]: any }>(
  obj: T,
  property: string | symbol | number
): property is keyof T {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, property)
}

// Then in user land somewhere:

interface Foo {
    bar: string
}

interface Fuzz {
    buzz: string
}

function doWork(thing: Foo | Fuzz) {
  if (has(thing, 'bar')) {
    alert(thing.bar) // ideally we've type narrowed to know thing contains foo
  }
}
```

The above code does not work how I would expect (`alert(thing.foo)`) does not know foo exists — obviously my type guard declaration `property is keyof T` doesn't do what I'm expecting.

**You could type guard the results to only be `Foo` or `Fuzz` — but I specifically want to type guard that a particular key exists on a generic.**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwBYCGAzgDwAqcoMwKAJkXAN5wDamdoAXHETFOwHMAutwIoAngG5W7WlzgokAWwBGwKCLhjxcAL4A%20ABQAoOHAgqAVtzIAaU3DBQIYdTHHde-FALgAfHnFVCAAbfwVlNShjAEpuJxc3HUwGAGtgcQgEOApGByhgGCQoXAB5K2AMADoEmAh3VyrCIlKAdxQABWdXWHEqtAIQkMMLS1tHbqSY411jYwB6eZy8Gjh2OCQidTgQsVoeCCVgVpWCzjn2aigEAjRgOAAxCAgmBzMVAihPPkEZi5Qrjc7o8kAAvUGvMzvMGg77eAR-YzIdBYHBwWgQADq0FShhgeEE3CeLwCDxhMUha2yhmaeIJPnGAHIPlBGTEKXkoVoQm46YIqiyKYs1nJBiEdK1gIyAG73Br3FCfZyS-Z1OCpFAQVpwfGCOBoHAwAjsBgIZ4OWa6IA)

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK8JKw) meet your needs?  Your type guard function was narrowing `property`, but you already know exactly what `"bar"` is.  Your use case seems to be that you want to narrow `obj` instead.  The version of `has` in my link only works if `obj` is of a union type.  If that works for your use cases, I'll write up an answer.  If not, please modify the question to elaborate your use cases and I'll look at it.  Let me know either way, and good luck.

Comment: That's a clever solution. I would really like the obj in to be any sort of object, not just unions. This seems super close though.

Comment: If you have a [mcve] of something that doesn’t work with my solution I could potentially update the solution. Without an example it’s harder to anticipate use cases you actually care about.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwBYCGAzgDwAqcoMwKAJkXBAEYBWwGANHANKUjV0GABSgQwwWAE9uwSQD4AFAFgAUHHWNWALjhkOqjXDCjxUnd1UBKHcxZxMDAKL8oBDOS4BvOAG0h93G4AXQB+HQIUSTgAXzk4TwMNKGAYJChcAHlWdhgAOmMIGELJcVzCIgyAdxQRMQkYSVy0AgAbFoVbLgLTBstVaNVVZHQsHDhaCAB1aABrBRg8TBQAcx0AJXZoWhJanulZLgj5S3jE9UwEOAVy+cWVrgByJgIoB8sThLVDDVb626XlrlnlA+l91AMVBDVGgcER4CAdJ4fEtaKAdHCoACguFIjE4ABeU5guDPABeOgAjAAmADM-UGKguVwAhDcQI8mEhSaS3h8znAQECuaSCXBqXTIUA) of an undesired effect where the `obj` gets narrowed to `never`

Comment: Why are you trying to do any narrowing whatsoever on something with a string index signature, and what would you like it to be narrowed to?  It seems that you should just access `x.buzz` directly like `x.buzz ??= 123`.   Anyway, try [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wgLk1N) with your use cases and let me know; I've given up on explicitly narrowing unions and have gone with intersections instead.  Please remember to add any use cases you care about to the question itself so the answer is not dependent on the state of comments.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. The intersection one makes a ton of sense to me — it almost works, but [in some cases I still get a type narrowing to "never"](http://brd.bz/ts). I'm not understanding why it's being coerced to never. For context this `has()` function is a generic utility used in hundreds of places in a javascript codebase that is moving to typescript. The example is contrived to yield a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkjdJm) work?  You won't get any meaningful narrowing if you are using `PropertyKey` or `string` for the value of the key.  I don't think I can play whack-a-mole with individual issues in the comments; if you can provide a [mcve], in the text of the question, that covers the extent of use cases you care about, great. Otherwise I will probably just post what I have and you can open a new question if the scope expands... since from the outside perspective you have an unobservably large issue that your example code doesn't reproduce, thus failing to be a [mre].

Comment: It's also quite possible that some use cases just can't be supported, period.  There are no "one-sided" or "fine grained" type guards of the form requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048), nor are there composable type guard predicates of the  form requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12798](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12798), nor negated types.  So we don't have complete control over what a type predicate does in both the `true` and the `false` case.

Comment: Cheers @jcalz  that seems correct and the idea to overload the dissimilar situations is what I never arrived at. Happy to accept as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want `has(obj, k)` to act as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  The use cases we are trying to support with `has(obj, k)` are:

- if `k` is of a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and `obj` is of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types where some of the union members explicitly have `k` as a key, then a `true` result should narrow `obj` to just those members with `k` as a key, and a `false` result should narrow `obj` to just those members without `k` as a key.  This is currently how [the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) narrows an object via `k in obj`.  It is not [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), since [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing) means that an object of type `{x: string}` may well have more keys than just `x`, so you can't safely eliminate `{x: string}` from the list of possibilities when you check for a key of, say, `y`.  But this is how the `in` operator works today, so we might as well do the same thing for `has()`.
- if `k` is of a single literal type and `obj` is *not* of a union type, and if that non-union type does not have an explicit property value at key `k`, then a `true` result should narrow `obj` to have an explicit `unknown` property value at key `k`.  A `false` result should not narrow `obj` at all.  This is not currently the `in` operator narrows in TypeScript, although there is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) to support this.
- if `k` is of a wide property type such as `string`, `number`, `symbol`, or `PropertyKey`, then we don't want to narrow `obj` at all for either a `true` or a `false` result.  It's *possible* one might want to narrow `k` in such situations, but this has not been explicitly called out as a use case, so I will not pursue that.  For now I will say that in such a situation, the return value of `has()` will just be `boolean`.
- if `k` is of a *union* of literal types, then presumably we want to narrow `obj` in the same way as the first two situations: if `obj` is a union then narrow down `obj` to just those union members with/without an explicit key matching any of the possible values of `k`; if `obj` is not a union then narrow `obj` into something which is itself a union of object types with each possible member of the union of `k` as one member of the result.  This was not explicitly stated as a requirement, but it's better to do this than anything else I can think of (the simplest implementation of `has()` returning `true` would narrow `obj` to something having *all* the keys from the union of `k`, which is considerably worse).

---

With those use cases in mind, here's a potential implementation of `has()`:

```
export function has<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: T,
    property: RequireLiteral<K>
): obj is T & { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: unknown } }[K];
export function has(obj: any, property: PropertyKey): boolean;
export function has(obj: any, property: PropertyKey) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, property)
}

type RequireLiteral<K extends PropertyKey> =
    string extends K ? never :
    number extends K ? never :
    symbol extends K ? never :
    K
```

This is an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) where the first call signature is only invoked in situations where `property` is of a literal type or a union of literal types.  The `RequireLiteral<K>` type function will return `K` if so, otherwise it will return `never`.  In any case, the return type predicate type narrows `obj` to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its original type, and a type with an `unknown` property at each key in `K`.  That `{[P in K]:{[Q in P]:unknown}}[K]` type might be easier described by example: if `K` is `"a"`, then it is `{a: unknown}`; if `K` is `"a" | "b"`, then it is `{a: unknown} | {b: unknown}`.  This call signature should result in all the behavior we want to support where `property` is not a wide type.

The second call signature is invoked only when `property` is a wide type like `string` or `PropertyKey`.  If so, the function does not act as a type guard.

---

We can verify that the stated examples work as desired:

```
function doWork(thing: Foo | Fuzz) {
    if (has(thing, 'bar')) {
        // Foo
        thing.bar
    } else {
        // Fuzz
        thing.buzz
    }
}

const x: { [index: string]: any } = {
    baz: 123
}
if (!has(x, 'buzz')) {
    /*  { [index: string]: any; } */
    x.buzz = 123        
} else {
    /* { [index: string]: any; } & { buzz: unknown; } */
    x.buzz 
}


const y: { [index: string]: any } = {}
const key: PropertyKey = 'a'
if (!has(y, key)) {
    // { [index: string]: any; }
    y[key] = 123 
} else {
    // { [index: string]: any; }
    y
}
```

Looks good!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-b3xP35IOQ8O9cZS+X6-ba1cl3IWwuoPvB-bh+QxxOjyfg-Op7ro1GDdQjZ7oOdEBRi+IkJ+w865EJB9RFjEF0mhCUMlwKtM27HN8x9f08ygD8KEPKdNwrcF9yqABZPB02FfA6FYUxmiLIgoAABmFABWPwoAAIgbRiDCY29fUY5tv2nfcZy7bNkMQgNp3Ec9R3HHjjBPX8v1nVg7jwEA12jDcy2aZp8MI4iEzIijqLohjmPtViumYkMuL3asDykvtrP4zQc2oe02CeCMxPvC9JMnUTF2s4VZIc3A2FQFSnxEZzTAgegwFNaAAElaC-HyJESNIpCgChTl2WRaEof8IxuaEQA+QRbNtPBQygABGAAmABmMKp1nJ4MhKx5SRKRApD6CgVyQtQ1AEGqGr1PpMIAQkrCg6w4pt0N8mcACpxDOXL8skcN5CKmFvlKpb2yPPqOLKur6sW8TL3K5athyugNqdQr6RAPb3g2bYOK6e5HheV6oAOo7+oDWdvueagVOA6NIui2KvUTZA8oxa0+jS6gMqRW6dnWrLNoAnaSveYbNgfYxUYyu4eBZTV0R4MrazwWtxvUqbwVhKAKcxBbfJAHYOaOU6Goc2csfunHHu257CWMEcrpS0SSuF7GColqBiqliRIbU8sJuaDmrk566eb5gXGs8iSrynYwFa7EW8rFra5Hx9XxAfV4gA)

Comment: Nice implementation of typeguard!